# Handling with sqllite3 and sqllite script

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a simple SQLite file with SQLite extension.

I can connect to ":memory:" by a simple statement which is written in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)

```
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
```

but if I have an outer SQLite script (let's say `example.sqlite`) and if I want to connect to this DB what should I do?

Should I execute this script by some side software and then establish a connection somehow? But how in this case?

I understand that if I go with

```
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
```

then I can create DB in my RAM and manipulate with this somehow. But I cannot understand how can I connect to the "existing" SQLite database? At first, I must create it, but how? I cannot find a command to execute the SQL script inside of the python-module.

For example, in case of MySQL DB, I use PyMySql driver, then I enter credentials and good to go

hope I made it clear.. this is my first question and I am ready for the worst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At first I must create it, but how?

You don't need to create database files first in SQLite. If the file exists, a connection will be opened. If the file doesn't exist, it will be created for you.

```
con = sqlite3.connect('path/to/some/file.db')  # or use :memory:
```

> but if I have an outer sqlite script (lets say example.sqlite) and if I want to connect to this db what should I do?

If the file is just regular SQL (creating tables etc, inserting data), you can [execute](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.executescript) it on the connection:

```
with open('path/to/example.sqlite', encoding='utf8') as file:
    sql = file.read()
    con.executescript(sql)
    con.commit()
```

This creates the DB as described by the SQL and of course it only needs to be done once.

If your script file contains "dot commands" such as `.import some.txt some_table` - these can only be understood by the sqlite command line client, you can't execute them through Python. Use a shell script/batch file to execute them.